# WCF Service Make DataMembers Required? What am I missing?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, datacontract

I am making a WCF service, and I want to make certain DataMembers which are string values of my requests required (i.e., not null, not empty), because we have institutional/legal  access logging requirements to sensitive data (we need to log by whom and when the access was made)

I'm guessing that some of this is the fact that my DataMembers are strings, and that strings that are null can be valid.  Can anyone help me with this definition?

```
namespace CrdWcfServiceInterface.Request
{
    [DataContract]
    public class GetPatientDemographicsRequest
    {
       [DataMember]
       public string PatientID { get; set; }
       [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
       public string RequesterLanID { get; set; }
       [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
       public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at integrating the Enterprise library blocks to handle the validation alongwith WCF as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664526%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but since I have to use the 4.0 framework on our production environment, I can't use Enterprise Library yet, since it uses 4.5

Comment: Enterprise Library 5 works perfectly with .NET 4.0, I use it everyday with WCF services... it works great. Just an FYI